# Writing simple windows server app(Visual c++) so iPhone / Android can retrieve values over Wifi

Tags: c++, objective-c, web-services, visual-c++

I want to write a server app(Visual c++) so iPhone / Android can retrieve values over Wifi.
But what can I do keep this simple?  What do I need to focus on?  What is a flow to follow.
What other components do I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asume you need Win.App. (VC++ and req. Win2003/WinXP SP2) <-- ip --> iPhone etc.

Depends on the required performance and protocol:
 1. Any protocol, Low-Perf. - Sync/Async(nonblocked, overlapped) Winsock
 2. Any protocol, High-Perf. - I/o completion ports (thread pooling) +
    Overlapped Winsock 
 3. Http, High-Perf. - HTTP Server API

Your application/logic may be wrapped into:
 1. simple console-app ( printf("Hello world"); )
 2. windows-app ( windows controls )
 3. windows service-app ( background application on system level )

Server applications are usually made as a windows service.

All of these you can make using Visual Studio Express Edition + Windows SDK + MSDN. 
Look at WindowsSDK/Samples and "All-in-one framework" for samples.

Answer (score 0):

write a isapi program and deploy to iis。